# php arithmatic operations between two different data types

Tags: php

hi first of all I'm new to here.

i need all of your help

below is my coding

```
<?php


 $a=1; 
 $b="hello";

$c=$a+$b."<br>"; 
$d=$b+$a."<br>";

 echo $c; 
 echo $d;
?>
```

output

1

1

i need to know whats happening 
why answer is 1 in both ways
is there any priority for data types in php

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: There's something important missing from the question: *what did you expect to happen?*

Answer (score 0):

### This scenario is otherwise called as **`Type-Juggling`**

The variable `$b="hello";` will be cast to `int` (in this case it will be a 0) when you did the addition operator. If the variable had `$b="2hello";` , your output would have been **`3`**

See this code.

```
<?php
$foo = "0";  // $foo is string (ASCII 48)
$foo += 2;   // $foo is now an integer (2)
$foo = $foo + 1.3;  // $foo is now a float (3.3)
$foo = 5 + "10 Little Piggies"; // $foo is integer (15)
$foo = 5 + "10 Small Pigs";     // $foo is integer (15)
?>
```

[`PHP Manual`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Comment: is there any priority for data type conversions

Comment: This is most close answer to your question. `An example of PHP's automatic type conversion is the addition operator '+'. If either operand is a float, then both operands are evaluated as floats, and the result will be a float. Otherwise, the operands will be interpreted as integers, and the result will also be an integer. `

Answer (score 0):

Your `$a` is an integer and `$b` is an string. When you add integer to string, string is converted to integer. In your case `$b = "hello"` is converted to integer `0`.

Comment: is there any priority for data types

Comment: @Susantha7 not exactly, but maybe this one will help you: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.type-juggling